# Is posting a word game accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions

Can I post word games (as community wiki) on this site? It will improve vocabulary. I would like an answer from a moderator.

Comment: There wont be any community Moderators [appointed to this site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) for about two weeks. But you are going about this the correct way. Use meta to determine if there is a consensus in the community as to whether this is on or off topic.

Comment: Agreed. The moderators on SE sites don't really make the rules or resolve disputes. They act more like facilitators that clean things up and do administrative chores. The community is supposed to be defining the rules.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  the nearest equivalent to a word game on EL&U is the “single word request“ which attracts massively divisive opinions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Noted, but not convinced that that is grounds for 'closing' this genuine discussion on meta. Explain that in an answer if you can, please.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, I would prefer that such word games are left out; the reason is that there are too much variations for the same word game.

Answer (score 5):

A decade+ later, I think very few people on this site would agree with  the 'yes' in the [(since deleted) accepted answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/53/1). Though the tag [word-games](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-games) has 21 questions, very few of [the un-closed, un-locked ones](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bword-games%5D%20closed%3Ano%20locked%3Ano) are actual word *games*, probably because puzzles and stuff aren't *really* about the English language and its usage; posting one will most likely result in your question's closure.

This may not be useful if the goal (as is yours) is to improve people's vocabulary, but [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), which has tags for [[wordplay]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/wordplay), [[word-game]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-game), and [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), is one place where such word games may be posted. Apparently, [EL&U chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage-multi-layered-discourse-room) is also a place for this, although you probably wouldn't be able to post more elaborate games.

Comment: Perhaps not a good idea to bump a 10-year-old question on meta, especially seeing no one has recently asked a similar question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, on many discussion sites on the Internet resurrecting old thread is perceived as bad manners, but I don't think that has ever been the case here, In fact, responding to and commenting on years-old posts is quite common on this site. As I understand the general purposes of the Stack Exchange, it is meant to be a repository of expertise and insight for an indefinite future. The visitors to it are thus entitled to assume that everything that appears anywhere on it is to be taken seriously regardless of when it was posted. If things change, it is helpful for that to be noted.

Comment: While agreeing with this answer, I would probably add that it should not inhibit anyone from posting questions that are inspired or prompted by something one has encountered in a game, as long as the question is formulated so that it leads to an insight about the language that goes beyond the game.

Comment: @jsw29 The OP talked about word games, not questions about the language or vocabulary used in games, whether they be puzzles or sports. I'm positive questions on language used in the football World Cup and the Olympics have been asked before. Nothing wrong with that. In any case, the post was composed way back in 2010, it has attracted a mere 161 visitors since then, so safe to say it would have been better to leave the post dormant.

Comment: Word games would also be accepted in our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95) (which doesn't have many rules about what you can post there anyway). I think the regulars would enjoy it.

Comment: In the chat forum, there are too many games posted, imo. And you can't even see the answers to them. Just that the posters were able to do them in so many tries. [sigh]